# Need to group records by consecutive date SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, query-optimization, gaps-and-islands

I'm building a query in order to build consecutive dates which is

```
create table #consecutivedates (
    sgid nvarchar(max), 
    metric nvarchar(max), 
    targetvalue nvarchar(max), 
    startdate datetime, 
    enddate datetime
)

insert into #consecutivedates values 
    ('2177', '515818', '18', '2019-09-01',  '2019-09-30'),
    ('2177', '515818', '125', '2019-08-01',  '2019-08-31'),
    ('2177', '515818', '15', '2019-07-01',  '2019-07-31')

SELECT  sgid,metric, CAST(startdate AS DATE) startdate, CAST(enddate AS DATE) enddate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY sgid, metric, startdate ) rn
INTO    #temp
FROM    #consecutivedates

-- GroupingColumn in cte used to identify and group consecutive dates
;WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   sgid ,
          metric , 
                        startdate ,
                        enddate ,
                        1 AS GroupingColumn ,
                        rn
               FROM     #temp
               WHERE    rn = 1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   t2.sgid ,
               t2.metric,
                        t2.startdate,
                        t2.enddate ,
                        CASE WHEN t2.startdate = DATEADD(day, 1, cte.enddate) 
                                  AND cte.sgid = t2.sgid AND cte.metric=t2.metric
                             THEN cte.GroupingColumn
                             ELSE cte.GroupingColumn + 1
                        END AS GroupingColumn ,
                        t2.rn
               FROM     #temp t2
                        INNER JOIN cte ON t2.rn = cte.rn + 1
             )
    SELECT  sgid,metric, MIN(startdate) AS startdate, MAX(enddate) AS enddate
    FROM    cte
    GROUP BY sgid,metric, GroupingColumn

DROP TABLE #temp
DROP TABLE #consecutivedates
```

but I'm facing a problem with two things.

1. query is too expensive when files are big.
2. if the dates are something like

   startdate             enddate
   '2019-08-01'         '2019-09-30' 
   '2019-10-01'         '2019-10-31'

Then the query will not group the dates and I need it to be smart enough to solve this kind of cases.

Any help would be nice,

Thanks.

Comment: (1) Tag the question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: This is a "Gaps & Island" problem, but you are trying to solve it using a recursive CTE. I would suggest you change your strategy and use window frames instead.

Comment: When you group rows, you are dropping the `targetvalue` column. I assume is not necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I undersand that you want to group together records that have the same `sgid` and `metric` and that are adjacent (ie next record starts one day after the end of the current record).

Here is a gaps and island solution that uses window sum to define the groups:

```
select sgid, metric, min(startdate) startdate, max(enddate) enddate
from (
    select
        t.*,
        sum(case when startdate = dateadd(day, 1, lag_enddate) then 0 else 1 end)
            over(partition by sgid, metric order by startdate) grp
    from (
        select 
            t.*, 
            lag(enddate) over(partition by sgid, metric order by startdate) lag_enddate
        from  #consecutivedates t
    ) t
) t
group by sgid, metric, grp
```

For your sample data, where all three records are adjacent, this produces:

```
sgid | metric | startdate               | enddate                
:--- | :----- | :---------------------- | :----------------------
2177 | 515818 | 2019-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2019-09-30 00:00:00.000
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e00433c04c497b3256853d7f976d0a7d)**

Note that the query uses SQL Server date functions (which I suspect that you are using): alternatives exists in other databases.

Answer (score 0):

Window frames could be more performant, but you'll need to test it. Here's the alternative solution:

```
select sgid, metric, min(startdate) as mindate, max(enddate) as maxdate
from (
  select *,
    sum(case when startdate > dateadd(day, 1, prev_enddate) then 1 else 0 end)
      over(partition by sgid, metric order by startdate) as grp
  from (
    select 
      sgid, metric, startdate, enddate,
      max(enddate)
        over(partition by sgid, metric order by startdate 
             rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_enddate
    from #consecutivedates
  ) x
) y  
group by sgid, metric, grp
```

Result (with more comprehensive data script):

```
sgid  metric  mindate                maxdate              
----  ------  ---------------------  ---------------------
2177  515818  2019-03-01 00:00:00.0  2019-03-31 00:00:00.0
2177  515818  2019-07-01 00:00:00.0  2019-09-30 00:00:00.0
2177  515818  2019-11-01 00:00:00.0  2019-11-30 00:00:00.0
2177  515820  2019-10-01 00:00:00.0  2019-10-31 00:00:00.0
```

Here's the data script I used:

```
create table #consecutivedates (sgid nvarchar(max), metric nvarchar(max), 
  targetvalue nvarchar(max), startdate datetime, enddate datetime);

insert into #consecutivedates values
  ('2177', '515818', '18', '2019-09-01',  '2019-09-30'),
  ('2177', '515818', '125', '2019-08-01',  '2019-08-31'),
  ('2177', '515818', '15', '2019-07-01',  '2019-07-31'),
  ('2177', '515820', '15', '2019-10-01',  '2019-10-31'),
  ('2177', '515818', '15', '2019-03-01',  '2019-03-31'),
  ('2177', '515818', '15', '2019-11-01',  '2019-11-30')
```